# Pass a 4x4 matrix as layout in C and OpenGL

Tags: c, matrix, opengl, glsl

I'm working on 2D batching, for which I need to keep every uniform I don't want to share between textures as a layout instead of a regular uniform.
I've come to a point where I need to move my `MVP (model view projection)` matrix to the vertices aka layout.

The only problem I'm facing is **in which order should I keep the matrix?**

In the current order the texture is not displayed in the right place.

To clarify here's an example:

```c
GLfloat indices[] = {
    /* ... */
}

mat4 bar = some_init_function();
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    /* Some var   */                  /* current mat4 order doesn't work */
    foo, foo1, foo2,  bar[0][0], bar[0][1], bar[0][2], bar[0][3], bar[1][0], bar[1][1], 
    foo, foo1, foo2,  bar[0][0], bar[0][1], bar[0][2], bar[0][3], bar[1][0], bar[1][1], /* . . . */ 
    foo, foo1, foo2,  bar[0][0], bar[0][1], bar[0][2], bar[0][3], bar[1][0], bar[1][1]
}

    glBindVertexArray(Renderer.VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Renderer.VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Renderer.EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /* Some var Attribute */
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,  19 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    /* MVP Attribute [4][4] */
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 16, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 19 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: "*as a layout instead of a regular uniform*" What is a "layout"? Do you mean a UBO?

Comment: you can use 4x `vec4` instead of `mat4` to pass to shaders and then reconstruct the `mat4` in vertex shader